# Want Autorelease lifetime with ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Transitioning to ARC on iOS.

I have an autoreleased NSString that I use to generate a UTF-8 representation, and rely on pool lifetime to keep the UTF-8 pointer alive:

```
char *GetStringBuffer(something)
{
    NSString *ns = [NSString stringWithSomething:something];
    return [ns UTF8String];
}
```

The nature of `something` is not important here.

Pre-ARC rules make sure the returned data pointer will stay valid for the lifetime of current autorelease pool. Crucially, I don't carry the NSString pointer around.

Now, under ARC, won't the string be released when the function returns? I don't think ARC will consider a `char *` to a structure deep inside an NSString a strong reference, especially seeing that it's not explicitly freed ever.

What's the best ARC idiom here?

Comment: Are you having an issue with that code under ARC? `ns` is still autoreleased under ARC.

Comment: Yes, but the question is *when*?

Comment: ARC doesn't change how autorelease works. Nothing changes in that regard. All ARC does is implicitly add `release` and `retain` when needed. It sounds like you are worrying about a problem that doesn't actually exist or you haven't encountered.

Comment: In other words, your code is fine.

Comment: So the Cocoa objects that are allocated with [objectWithXXX] still get the same lifetime as before?

Comment: Sure. Why would ARC change that?

Comment: @rmaddy `ns` is not returned so there is no need for ARC to autorelease `ns`. `ns` will be probably released immediately on method exit.

Comment: No live strong references=time to kill, no? How can I test that?

Comment: @Sulthan But `ns` is an `autoreleased` object created from `NSString stringWithFormat`. So just like with MRC, ARC will autorelease it the same way - through the current autorelease pool.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, you are right... Still I would consider code relying on such behavior a bit unsafe.

Comment: @rmaddy, I've personally seen code like the above crash under ARC. `ns` is an automatic variable and does not have precise lifetime semantics (see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#precise-lifetime-semantics), so ARC is free to destroy it before the `char*` is consumed. This is dangerous code. See Mark Dalrymple's discussion here for a specific example: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/

Comment: @RobNapier I agree. My main point is that the behavior under ARC for this situation shouldn't be any different than it was under MRC.

Comment: But it often will be. Mark's code in the linked article would traditionally have been fine under MRC, but crashes under ARC. I've experienced exactly the same thing. ARC doesn't make the same promise about autorelease pools that MRC (at least implicitly) makes. Taking inner pointers (like `UTF8String`) is exactly the kind of thing that blows up.

Comment: Have to take some of that back. While *ARC* doesn't promise to save this till the autorelease pool pops, `UTF8String` *does* promise it by being marked `objc_returns_inner_pointer`. I'd forgotten that they'd added that at some point to save people from exactly this. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that the return value of `UTF8String` is valid until the current autorelease pool is drained, you have two options:

1. Define `GetStringBuffer` in a file that is [compiled with ARC disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6646052/77567). If `stringWithSomething:` follows convention, it must return an autoreleased `NSString` to a non-ARC caller. If it doesn't (e.g. it acts like `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`), you can explicitly `retain` and `autorelease` it.
2. Use toll-free bridging and `CFAutorelease`:

   ```
   char *GetStringBuffer(something) {
       NSString *ns = [NSString stringWithSomething:something];
       CFAutorelease(CFBridgingRetain(ns));
       return [ns UTF8String];
   }
   ```

Comment: This answer is correct, and my previous answer was misleading. There is no promise that the returned pointer from `UTF8String` is valid past the return statement. The ARC docs specifically say ["the implementation never need account for uses after a return"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#interior-pointers). See also https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/647807319649075200. I'm deleting my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the right way to do this was using `__autoreleasing`:

https://releases.llvm.org/11.1.0/tools/clang/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#storage-duration-of-autoreleasing-objects

E.g.

```
char *GetStringBuffer(something) NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER {
    __autoreleasing NSString * ns = [NSString stringWithSomething:something];

    return [ns UTF8String];
}
```

Comment: I think this should work. I haven’t tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

**(I can't delete this because it's accepted, but this answer is incorrect. See Rob Mayoff's answer, and the comments on that answer for an explanation. There is no promise that this pointer is valid past the return statement.)**

<strike>Rewriting my whole answer. Had to dig and dig, but I believe this is surprisingly safe today (due to improvements in ARC since I had my crashes; I knew something like that was rolling around in the back of my head). Here's why:</strike>

```
@property (readonly) __strong const char *UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;  // Convenience to return null-terminated UTF8 representation
```

`UTF8String` is marked `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER`, which is really [`objc_returns_inner_pointer`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id52). Calling that method:

> the object’s lifetime will be extended until at least the earliest of:
>
> - the last use of the returned pointer, or any pointer derived from it, in the calling function or
> - the autorelease pool is restored to a previous state.

Which is pretty much what you wanted it to do.

Comment: Any iOS version limits on that?

Comment: The problem here is that ARC is allowed to release the `NSString` as soon as his `GetStringBuffer` function returns, because that is the first bullet point you quoted.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I think it's at least back to iOS 6. It's not recent, but you'd have to look through release notes to see exactly.

Comment: @robmayoff The question is whether returning the pointer counts as creating a derived pointer. I assume it does (though I do not have proof of that position).

Comment: Verified that this was added in iOS 6 BTW. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011959

Comment: “the last use of the returned pointer, or any pointer derived from it, **in the calling function**” The “calling function” is `GetStringBuffer`. Even if `return` creates a “derived pointer”, any use of that “derived pointer” is outside of the calling function.

Comment: So returning the pointer doesn't hint the compiler that it might be used by the caller? :)

Comment: The only thing it could actually do at that point is force it onto the autorelease pool (it doesn't know who the caller is). My bet is that that's exactly what happens. But @robmayoff has a reasonable point that it's not explicitly promised.

Comment: If `UTF8String` were compiled with ARC (which it probably isn't, since it's old code), and the caller (`GetStringBuffer`) were compiled with ARC, then `UTF8String` can (by way of `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue`) hand off ownership of the returned object to `GetStringBuffer` (by way of `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`), instead of putting it in the autorelease pool. Then `GetStringBuffer` can release the string before returning. See [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/) and [this](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/75082194868/arcs-fast-autorelease).

Comment: @robmayoff Yeah; I know the horror stories (I had them myself; I linked the BNR article up above :D). But objc_returns_inner_pointer adjusts that behavior. Mark's problem wouldn't happen today because the `CGColor` property is now marked `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER`. That's why they added that inner pointer attribute, because people kept getting burned by surprising ARC releases. The inner pointer attribute extends the lifetime based on the returned (and "derived") pointers. The only question is whether "returned pointer" is a "derived pointer." I think it is, but might be wrong.

Comment: Note the "*at least* the earliest of..." They can conform to this spec by throwing it on the autorelease pool if the pointer escapes, and my reading of it is that's what they likely do. (But your answer is absolutely safer because there's no ambiguity at all. No argument there for OS X 10.9 and above, which is always above what I can use :D The question is iOS of course, and that goes back to 7, which is darn good.)